# Android studio 2.2.3. Unable to fix app:_ debugAndroidTestApkCopy

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I have worked in previous version of android. When i tried to update facing this problem. Please suggest

Thank uou

Comment: where is my OCR software to get the error of this image to a text..

Comment: @CharukaSilva
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugAndroidTestApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
     Required by:
         MyApplication:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
      > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
         > Could not parse Ivy file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a mater of protocol:
If you are requesting help resolving a problem like this, DO NOT paste a photo of the issue displayed on a monitor. You are much more likely to get help if you paste the error text from Android Studio directly into your post.

That said: your first issue appears to be resolving 'javawriter' from 'com.squareup'.  See the gradle tab [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup/javawriter/2.2.1)

This should appear in the dependencies section of your build.gradle script.

```
dependencies {

...

androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much fir suggestion and solution. @gOnzo